# How does one use the ? in a SOQL query?

Tags: apex, soql

According to the [documentation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/)

> In a syntax statement, the question mark indicates the element
> preceding it is optional. You may omit the element or include one.

I've never seen a SOQL statement using the ? and in my tests with the Query Editor in the Developers Console only results in errors.

Can anybody tell me how to use the ? in a SOQL, and what it might be good for?

Comment: These are typographical conventions to read the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't use "?" in a query.   They're saying it marks an optional query element.  Here's an example from the documentation:

```
[ORDER BY fieldExpression ASC | DESC ? NULLS FIRST | LAST ?]
```

So if you include an "Order By" in your query, the "ASC | DESC" and "FIRST | LAST" elements are optional.

(You appear to be quoting from the [SOQL Typographical Conventions](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_typos.htm) which relate to documentation syntax rather than SOQL syntax.)

Answer (score 3):

These are [typographical conventions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_typos.htm) to read the document. So, you could understand it better and implement in example.

Ex:

SELECT *fieldname* FROM objectname

> In an example or syntax statement, italics represent variables. You
>   supply the actual value.